# nVarchar and SqlParameter

Tags: c#, nvarchar, sqlparameter

I'm developing an application which must support several languages. To solve the special characters problem I'm using NVarhcar for my text fields. So my SQL query for a text field is

```
insert into tbl_text(text)values(N'Chci tančit v oblasti')
```

My problem is to put it in SqlCommand, wich is `"insert into tbl_text(text)values(N@text)"`. It saves `"N@text"` in the DB table, sure.

Do you guys know someway to do it? I'm using C# and SQL 2008.

Sorry if it was hard to understand my question. My English is poor =/

Comment: How does your statement even work at all? I get `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'N@text'.` when trying to reproduce the insertion of `N@text` into the `tbl_text.text` column from within SSMS.

Answer (score 4):

*Add(string, object)* has been deprecated for this reason (from Pablo Castro of the SQL Server team):

> The problem is that both the C# and
>   the VB.NET compilers will expose very
>   weird behavior for this code:
>
> command.Parameters.Add(“@p”, 0);
>
> you may expect this to use the
>   overload that takes an object and
>   assign the value 0 to it, but instead
>   it will pick the overload that takes a
>   SqlDbType as the second parameter! In
>   order to avoid this (and potentially
>   others) ambiguity between the
>   Add(string, sqldbtype) and Add(string,
>   object), we deprecated Add(string,
>   object) and introduced
>   AddWithValue(string, object). In
>   general, having multiple overloads
>   where the distinguishing parameter
>   type is “object” in one of them is a
>   dangerous thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You should parametrize your inserts with [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) which allow you to specify the datatype explicitly. (Also it saves you the headache of figuring out the SQL server injection attack your query caused).

**Example:**

```
SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_text (text) values(@MYTEXT)", myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MYTEXT", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = "Chci tančit v";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I would change the methof of Add to AddWithValue because Add is deprecated... i do not have the computer right now so I can't give you the exact code... but if no one answers, when I get home I'll sure post it :)

Comment: @PredoC88 where do you get that info from? Just checked http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht4eset1.aspx and it doesn't appear to be deprecated.

Comment: @BrokenGlass he was referring to [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(string, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29) which is a convenience method. You should really be using `IDbCommand.CreateParameter()` instead of instantiating `SqlParameter` directly and drop the `@` from your `SqlParameter` to reduce your dependence on the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace :-p.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put "N" before the parameter name, it is only used when using string constant to indicate it is a unicode string. So your query should be:

```
insert into tbl_text(text) values (@text)
```

Comment: I do not recommend this thought for it leaves you wide open for sql injection, go for the other procedures using SQLParameter... it's really easy to use and much safer.

Comment: Using @text implies that it was ment to be used with SQL Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQLParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Here is a simple example:

```
var cmd = _dbCon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText =
    "insert into tbl_text (textfield) values(@textfield)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@textfield", "Chci tančit v oblasti"));
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Why did you change the č to a question mark? Are you using obsolete 1980s software to access this website? (I’ve fixed it for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple Example

```
String filePath = @"D:\" + FileName;
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandText = 
    @"DECLARE @TraceId INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM sys.traces WITH (NOLOCK))
    SET @TraceId=@TraceId+1

    DECLARE @File NVARCHAR(256);
    Set @File= (@filePath)

    SET @TraceId=@TraceId+1 --Var olandan bir fazla

    DECLARE @MaxFileSize BIGINT = 1 /* max size of file as MegaByte*/
    DECLARE @FileCount INT = 1024 /* max file count for write*/

    exec sp_trace_create @traceid = @TraceId OUTPUT,
                                    @options = 2,
                                    @tracefile = @File,
                                    @maxfilesize = @MaxFileSize, 
                                    @stoptime = NULL,
                                    @filecount = @FileCount

    SELECT @TraceId";

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@filePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = filePath;
```